# How to create [ 12,24, 13,21] from multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I am really struggling with javascript arrays and objects.
I need to create this structure (array? or ..? unsure of what it is),

```
 data = [ 12, 24, 13, 21]
```

for a chart.js chart dynamically, from an array.
The array is created as

```
yAxisArray.push(singularYaxisDataArray);
```

where

```
var singularLabelArray = [];
singularLabelArray has values 12, 24, 13, 21 pushed into it.
```

and 'yAxisArray' could have several singularLabelArray 's in it, which would mean iterating them all
to create several of these structures "data = [ 12, 24, 13, 21]"  to put into this

```
var datasources = [
        {
            label: "Budgeted",
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            data: [12, 24, 13, 21]
        },
        {
            label: "Actual",
            backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
            data: [408, 547, 675, 734]
        }
    ];
```

Iterating the yAxisArray is not the issue , but can't get the structure out of it that I need.

```
for (idx = 0; idx < yAxisArray.length; idx++)
            {
                var datasources = 
                {
                    label: labelArray[idx],
                    **data: yAxisArray[idx],**
                    backgroundColor: colorsList[idx],
                }
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: There's nothin multidimensional here, but from your formatting it's unclear whether you are talking about the four values `[ 12, 24, 13, 21]` or two values `[ 12.24, 13.21]`

Comment: Hi thanks, they are 4 values (deciamls), hence the period.

Comment: Q? Why is it not multidimensional?

Comment: There are simple arrays  (i.e  one or more singularLabelArray) pushed onto the YAxisArray? thx

Comment: A multidimensional array would look like `[[1,2], [3,4]]` - nothing in your code has this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare var outside loop and use push method. Should work.
(If not, Can you add the `yAxisArray` data and expected)

```
var datasources = [];
for (idx = 0; idx < yAxisArray.length; idx++) {
  datasources.push({
    label: labelArray[idx],
    data: yAxisArray[idx],
    backgroundColor: colorsList[idx],
  });
}
```